# Why multiply by 2 when accessing program memory using Z register on AVR ASM

Tags: assembly, memory, avr

*I know that [this question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305155/avr-asm-label2) and that it has been answered but while I am getting what the answers are saying I just don't get **why** this answers answer the question.*

On the AVR ASM microcontroller, when I access program memory using the Z pointer why do I have to multiply the address that I load on the ZH/ZL registers by two?

Here is the sample code:

```
ldi ZL, low(2*label)
ldi ZH, high(2*label)

label:
.db "Hello world", 0
lpm
```

This is what I know so far from the research I have done on the Internet (*the sources are just too limited*):

- *Program memory is word addressed while registers are byte addressed* : what I understand from this statement is that an address in program memory (`16 bit`) includes `2 bytes` while registers on the AVR are `8-bit`. So in order to load data to the registers you need to choose which one of the two bytes you want to load from the memory address.
- *The `LSB` of the Z pointer chooses which byte will be loaded* : that means that there are only `15-bits` for you (in the Z pointer) to specify the program memory address from which you will load the data.

So multiplying by 2 apparently solves the problem but I don't get why. Rephrasing the question I could say:

While I need to load data say from memory `0x4322`, I say to Z pointer to load data from memory address `0x8644` because that's the byte address. How does the assembled know that?

Side question:

I have seen this kind of implementation:

```
ldi ZL, low(label)
ldi ZH, high(label)

lsl ZL
rol ZH
label:
.db "Hello world", 0
lpm
```

If the label program memory address is `0b10110011 11000000`, executing the `lsl` and `rol` commands will result in a "byte" memory of `0b01100110 10000000` whith a C flag set (`C=1`). Given that there are two overflows here how is that pointing to the desired program memory byte?

Comment: The label is in program section so the assembler uses word addressing. To load as data you need byte address which is twice that much and then you get to pick which byte to load. It's as simple as that. As to the `lsl+rol` ... that is really silly, wasting instructions for something that can be done at assembly time. Still, there is no problem. The carry from the `lsl` is the topmost bit of `ZL` which needs to go to the bottom of `ZH` and the `rol` will do that. You don't know if `C=1` or not for the intermediate step, and after the `rol` it should be zero if your input was a valid address.

Comment: Program memory word address `0b10110011 11000000` is valid only for devices with more than 64KB flash. For these devices you must use carry flag to form `RAMPZ` value (for 256K-devices [the 3'd byte of address](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_ELPM.html) must be used). Also, `ELPM` instead of `LPM` is required for such devices.

Answer (score 1):

> While I need to load data say from memory `0x4322`, I say to Z pointer to load data from memory address `0x8644` because that's the byte address.

It's about the implied units of the constants: 0x4322 words is 0x8644 bytes (a *byte* on AVR is 8 bits, a *word* is defined to be 16 bits).

> How does the assembler know that?

That `LPM Z` is using byte addresses for `Z` can be concluded from the AVR Instruction Manual.  Which units are used for labels is up to the assembler you are using (*assembler* as tools that chews *assembly* code).  Thus the "assembler does know" because it's implicit in the assembler as implemented by its developers: *label* is nothing the AVR hardware knows about.

Moreover, there is more than one AVR assembler:  The GNU assembler is using labels in units of bytes.