# How do low() and high() functions work in AVR

Tags: assembly, avr

I am trying to understand some assembly code, and I'm not understanding how some values are found. If the code:

```
ldi     ZL, low(2*table)        
ldi     ZH, high(2*table)
```

Is executed with the table:

```
table:      .db     32, 34, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 64, 66
```

And I am looking at the element 5 of the table, 41.

What do the ldi operators do in this example? After the first ldi is executed, 14 is stored in the SRAM at the ZL location, but why is it 14?

After the second one is executed, 02 is stored at the ZH location.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the content of your table. It's loading the base address which is `0x020e` apparently.

Comment: So this value comes from where the table value is stored, and not based on the table value itself?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: What would the purpose be of loading the address of the table *multiplied by two*?

Comment: @ndim: I think that's normal for AVR; for some reason label addresses are the word number, and you need to scale to get the byte address.  Seems totally nuts to me, but I think I've seen this before.  (Although it might make sense for code addresses, if instructions are aligned.)

Answer (score 1):

Flash memory is "word addressed", the assembler label `table` gives the table's address in words. The `* 2` gives the correct address in bytes. I prefer to use `<< 1` rather than `* 2` as, to me, this makes things clearer.

To actually access the 5th Element of the table you would do something like this:

```
    ldi ZL, low(table << 1)  ; (or you could use `table * 2`)
    ldi ZH, high(table << 1) ; Z Register points to start of table
    ldi r25, 5               ; register r25 contains required offset in table
    clr r1                   ; (I always have r1 set to zero all the time)
    add ZL, r25              ; add offset to base pointer
    adc ZH, r1               ; if the low byte of the Z register "pointer"
                             ; overflowed, add the carry flag to the high byte
    lpm r24, Z               ; read the 5th element of the table into r24
```

This is also covered in the following SO questions:

- [Why multiply by 2 when accessing program memory using Z register on AVR ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929208/why-multiply-by-2-when-accessing-program-memory-using-z-register-on-avr-asm)
- [Avr asm label*2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305155/avr-asm-label2)
- [Why is this array pointer shifted by 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324623/why-is-this-array-pointer-shifted-by-1)

Comment: What do you mean "byte aligned" address?  I thought `table` gives you the address in words, e.g. the 10th word in memory, and you need `<<1` to get a byte address at all, e.g. 20th byte in memory, since AVR is byte addressable.

Comment: @PeterCordes "I thought": how very diplomatic of you! Of course you are quite right and I'll edit my answer immediately.

Comment: I have to leave the door open to being totally wrong about something, since everything I know about AVR is based on seeing SO questions about it, and occasional googling out of curiosity inspired by that.  And the address scaling seems like a weird design choice that doesn't make much sense.  But yeah, it took a couple tries at wording my understanding, and that's what I settled on. :P